# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"

Tags: android, android-fragments

Using the `EditaDatos` button function, automatically damages the functioning of the method Registrar, that already worked without problems

MyDB.java

```
public void addPersona(Personas personas) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBTables.EntradasTablas.COLUMN_DOCUMENTO, personas.getDocumento());
    values.put(DBTables.EntradasTablas.COLUMN_NOMBRE, personas.getNombre());
    values.put(DBTables.EntradasTablas.COLUMN_DIRECCION, personas.getDireccion());
    values.put(DBTables.EntradasTablas.COLUMN_TEL, personas.getTel());
    values.put(DBTables.EntradasTablas.COLUMN_EMAIL, personas.getEmail());
    values.put(DBTables.EntradasTablas.COLUMN_PASS, personas.getPass());

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(DBTables.EntradasTablas.TABLA_NOMBRE, null, values);
    db.close();

}

public Cursor personaPorId(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DBTables.EntradasTablas.TABLA_NOMBRE + " WHERE " + DBTables.EntradasTablas.COLUMN_DOCUMENTO + " = " + id + ";";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }

    return c;
}
```

and then, from the fragment I use the Intent to create the activity and pass the data

Cuenta.java

```
public class Cuenta extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    EditText EtEditDocu;
    Button EditaDatos;

    View vista;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cuenta, container, false);
        EtEditDocu = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.EtEditDocu);
        EditaDatos = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.EditaDatos);

        Typeface Titulos = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/EaDesignerBold.ttf");
        TituloActualizar.setTypeface(Titulos);

        EditaDatos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intento = new Intent(getActivity(), Registro.class);
                EtEditDocu = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.EtEditDocu);
                intento.putExtra("documento", EtEditDocu.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intento);
            }
        });

        return vista;
    }
}
```

Registro.java

```
public class Registro extends ActionBarActivity {

    MyDB MyDB;
    TextView Registrate;
    EditText EtDocuReg;
    EditText EtNombReg;
    EditText EtDirecReg;
    EditText EtTelReg;
    EditText EtEmailReg;
    EditText EtPassReg;
    Button Registrar;
    int idglobal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);
        Registrate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Registrate);
        EtDocuReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EtDocuReg);
        EtNombReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EtNombReg);
        EtDirecReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EtDirecReg);
        EtTelReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EtTelReg);
        EtEmailReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EtEmailReg);
        EtPassReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EtPassReg);

        MyDB = new MyDB(this, null, null, 1);
        Personas persona = new Personas();
        Intent intento = getIntent(); // intent creado anteriormente
        String Id = intento.getStringExtra("documento");
        long Documento = Long.parseLong(Id);
        Cursor c = MyDB.personaPorId(Documento);
        EtDocuReg.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("documento")));
        EtNombReg.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("nombre")));
        EtDirecReg.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("direccion")));
        EtTelReg.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("telefono")));
        EtEmailReg.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("email")));
        EtPassReg.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("contraseña")));
        idglobal = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));

        Typeface Titulos = Typeface.createFromAsset(Registrate.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/EaDesignerBold.ttf");
        Registrate.setTypeface(Titulos);
    }

    public void Registrar(View view) {
        Personas usuario = new Personas(Integer.parseInt(EtDocuReg.getText().toString()), EtNombReg.getText().toString(), EtDirecReg.getText().toString(), EtTelReg.getText().toString(), EtEmailReg.getText().toString(), EtPassReg.getText().toString());
        MyDB.addPersona(usuario);
        limpiarCampos();
        Confirmacion();
    }

    public void limpiarCampos() {
        EtDocuReg.setText("");
        EtNombReg.setText("");
        EtDirecReg.setText("");
        EtTelReg.setText("");
        EtEmailReg.setText("");
        EtPassReg.setText("");
    }

    public void Confirmacion() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dlgAlert.setMessage("Se ha agregado exitosamente!");
        dlgAlert.setTitle("Agregar Persona");

        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //dismiss the dialog
            }
        });

        dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
        dlgAlert.create().show();
    }
}
```

This is the error

```
12-31 13:10:42.426  20428-20428/com.example.leonardo.odontoexpress E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.leonardo.odontoexpress/com.example.leonardo.odontoexpress.Registro}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"
            at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:125)
            at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:342)
            at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:319)
            at com.example.leonardo.odontoexpress.Registro.onCreate(Registro.java:49)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace is fairly clear. It's caused by passing something that isn't parseable as a `long` into `Long.parseLong`. That in turn means that this line:

```
String Id = intento.getStringExtra("documento");
```

is putting either a `null` or the string `"null"` into the `Id` variable. Why the value is absent or set to that, I don't know. You need to plan out what happens when the value is absent; how do you recover, or failing that, how do you present the failure to the user? Do you present it at all? (Just crashing is an awful experience from the user's perspective.)

---

However, I really think it might be better to store the `documento` as a `long` in the first place as that's what you really want to use, and use `intento.getLongExtra("documento", SOME_DEFAULT)` to retrieve it. You'll need to pick what `SOME_DEFAULT` is; a sentinel like `-1` is probably a good idea, *provided you handle what happens when the value is missing*.

Bear in mind that values are particularly likely to be missing when a user first starts your app up, or when you interoperate with anything outside your app (including with older versions of your app). You've got to code defensively.